# Configure all options derived from base option class or interface .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I have code with variables in appsettings.json file so I register all options in IServiceCollection via configure method:

```
public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, bool useHangfire = true)
        {
            services
                .Configure<AuthSettings>(configuration.GetSection(AuthSettings.SectionName))
                .Configure<CacheSettings>(configuration.GetSection(CacheSettings.SectionName))
..... and so on
```

I would like to create a base(abstract) class or interface for example

```
public interface ISettings
    {
        public const string SectionName = "DefaultSettings";
    }
public class AuthSettings: ISettings
    {
        public const string SectionName = "AuthSettings";

        public int ConfirmCodeLength { get; set; }
        public string AllowedChars { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan ConfirmCodeExpiry { get; set; }
}
```

and configure all settings like this

```
foreach (var type in
                Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ISettings)).GetTypes()
                    .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ISettings))))
            {
                var currentSettings = (ISettings)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                services.ConfigureOptions(currentSettings);
            }
```

I have alredy done the same with registration of hangfire jobs but this case looks a bit different.
Unfortunately this version doesn't work bacause currentSetting should implenetn IConfigureOptions but it doesn't. Also i'm not sure that this code get values from JSON.
Did someone do something like this?

Comment: What's stopping you from doing it? What actual problem are you facing?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work.
services.ConfigureOptions requires argument that implements IConfigureOptions<TOptions> but it doesn't.
I don't know how do this in the right way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Registering multiple named types using reflection in Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55957415/registering-multiple-named-types-using-reflection-in-autofac)

Comment: @Harish Thank you! I just solve this problem via reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you has many settings you can create base class for all settings, that has method to define section name

```
public class BaseSettings
{
    public virtual string SectionName => this.GetType().Name;
}
```

and many settings-classes like this

```
public class AuthSettings:BaseSettings
{
    public int ConfirmCodeLength { get; set; }
    public string AllowedChars { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ConfirmCodeExpiry { get; set; }
}
```

Then in an ServiceCollection extention class set method to find all inherited classes and add it to IServiceCollection

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAllOptions(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        foreach (var type in
            Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseSettings)).GetTypes()
                .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseSettings))))
        {
            var configurationInstance = (BaseSettings)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            if (configurationInstance != null)
            {
                var configurationSection = configuration.GetSection(configurationInstance.SectionName);
                var configureMethod = typeof(OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions).GetMethods()
                    .Where(x => x.Name == "Configure")
                    .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                    .MakeGenericMethod(type);
                configureMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { services, configurationSection });
            }
        }

        return services;
    }
```

Finally you can use this method in your StartUp class

```
service.AddAllOptions(configuration);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer here helped me get my solution working but I found another approach using the dynamic type in .NET to create an instance of your class and pass the dynamic instance to an extension method to resolve the type of the  parameter at runtime. This uses the actual `Configure<T>` method instead of reflection to call the method.

```
foreach (var type in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ISettings)).GetTypes()
  .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract 
    && myType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(ISettings)))
{
  var currentSettings = (ISettings)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  var currentSettingsConfigurationSection = 
                    configuration.GetSection(currentSettings.Section);
  Configure(services, type, currentSettingsConfigurationSection );
}

private static IServiceCollection Configure(IServiceCollection services, Type type, IConfigurationSection section)
{
    dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    Configure(services, instance, section);
    return services;
}

private static IServiceCollection Configure<T>(IServiceCollection services, T _, IConfigurationSection section)
    where T : ISettings
{
    services.Configure<T>(section);
    return services;
}
```